# Which HTML element should semantically be used for a graph?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Say for instance a bar graph, which element(s) should be used to mark this up? Perhaps `<meter>` for each bar?

EDIT: What about using an SVG within a `<figure>`?

Comment: No, not a `<meter>`. [_"The `meter` element also does not represent a scalar value of arbitrary range — for example, it would be wrong to use this to report a weight, or height, unless there is a known maximum value."_](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-meter-element) I don't think there is a particularly semantic element.

Comment: Not supported in IE anyway. If they're mostly stand-alone graphs (not directly linked to the content but illustrative), I would think `<figure>` for the whole element.

Comment: @Matt Ball So what if the bar graph had a maximum value? Then would the use of `<meter>` be correct?

@shikkediel So if a `<figure>` could be used as a container for the graph; what about the individual “bars”?

Comment: A figure is fine if the SVG is in an img element. I think an svg element within the figure element should be fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<figure>` when you want to show content like illustrations, diagrams etc.
`<meter>` is used for content which has to be described in a certain range.